# Maven multi-module service/api project scope issue

Tags: maven

I have a maven multi-module project, which is called re-use, the structure looks like below:

```
root
  |__pom.xml: group=com.test.project, id=reuse, version=1.0.0
  |__api-module
     |__pom.xml: parent={group=com.test.project, id=reuse, version=1.0.0}, id=reuse-api
  |__service-module
     |__pom.xml: parent={group=com.test.project, id=reuse, version=1.0.0}, id=reuse-srv
```

I have another project "app" which uses the re-use dependencies, with different scopes:

```
root
  |__pom.xml: <dependency>
                <groupId>com.test.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>reuse-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
              </depedency>

              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.test.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>reuse-srv</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
              </depedency>
```

questions:

1. if I make some changes to re-use service module, is it possible to keep the api version as 1.0.0, but setting the service version to 1.0.0.1?
2. Is there a way when project "app" declares a partial wildcar dependency to re-use service, something like below:

   ```
             <dependency>
               <groupId>com.test.project</groupId>
               <artifactId>reuse-srv</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0.*</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
             </depedency>
   ```

   I just want to avoid re-compiling project "app", just because the re-use service module is changed. 
   And if the re-use api changes, then I will change the re-use api and service version to 1.0.1 and of course project "app" has to adapt and re-compile.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- Use SNAPSHOT versions for development. `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` will always resolve to the latest version that was deployed under that name.
- Use version ranges, like `[1.0.0,1.0.1)`. This has the same meaning as your `*`, but it is nowadays not a recommended practise.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a recommended practise for my use case? What is your suggestion? Thanks again.